# How to schedule an iOS call at an exact time in Swift?

Tags: ios, game-center, scheduler

There are some versions of this question where the OP says something like "how do I fire a method call inside my app at exactly 5pm?"

Then people answer with "how do you know your app will be open at 5pm"? And that becomes a whole other question and the original question disappears.

So let's please avoid that?

Let's just say I want to fire a method call at exactly 5:25pm and 30 seconds when my user opened the app at 5:25:28:50.

And if it isn't clear, I mean I want the *absolute time* that I can use whether my user opened the app at 5:25:26:35, 5:25:20:13, or 5:29:49:99.

Reading all around SO, it seems like the consensus (and the Apple docs recommendation) is to use some form of mach_absolute_time with dispatch_somethingOrOther. I just can't find any real, concrete examples.

The closest I've found is http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/dispatch_walltime/, which gives this example:

```
 Create a milestone on Tuesday, January 19, 2038:

       struct timespec ts;
       ts.tv_sec = 0x7FFFFFFF;
       ts.tv_nsec = 0;
       milestone = dispatch_walltime(&ts, 0);
```

I was like "eureka!" until I realized a) I don't know how to do the hexadecimal conversion that turns January 19, 2038 into 0x7FFFFFFF,  b) I don't understand how the `timespec` struct is constructed, and how I would add hours and minutes into it, and c) `milestone = dispatch_walltime(&ts, 0)` throws an error in Swift.

Can anyone help? If possible with the specific example of 5:25pm and 30 seconds?

Comment: Do you want to call a function call 40 seconds after the app is launched or do you want to do it at an exact date and time? For the the first one, you can use dispatch_after and place it somewhere in AppDelegate class - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or didBecomeActive.. For the latter, you can still check when the app launches and calculate the difference to the desired time. Both will fail if the app is not running, Apple is smart not to allow that. Starting with iOS 7 you can run background tasks, but there is no guarantee of the time it is run, so no use for your case.

Comment: @MartinKoles Thank you Martin! But the crucial bit of information is missing--yet so close! You say "calculate the difference to the desired time"--but how do you get that specific time--the mach way, *not* the NSDate way? --to use a specific example, 5:25pm and 30 seconds?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the mach way.. What is wrong with NSDate()? You get an exact date and time with miliseconds of the app start, you have somewhere your desired date and time, you calculate miliseconds between them and dispatch_after a specific function call. What am I missing?

Comment: @MartinKoles I admit I'm a little confused by all the different approaches here, but as I understand it NSDate and dispatch_after are measuring time differently. dispatch_after is using time based on mach_absolute_time, which is more accurate. On the other hand, according to what I've read, if you poll NSDate ten times in a row you aren't guaranteed to get results in numerically ascending order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an NSDate for the time you want, depending on timezone and daylight savings time (this is slightly tricky but plenty of answers on Stackoverflow). Then

```
   struct timespec ts;
   ts.tv_sec = (int64_t) [date timeIntervalSince1970];
   ts.tv_nsec = 0;
   milestone = dispatch_walltime(&ts, 0);
   dispatch_after (dispatch_get_main_queue (), milestone, ^ (...));
```

The block will be dispatched at the time you want, even if the user adjusts the clock in between.

Just saying: dispatch_after behaves differently depending on how you created the dispatch_time_t. dispatch_time (DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delta) returns a time based on mach_absolute_time. dispatch_wall_time (...) returns a wall time. dispatch_after behaves different depending on what time it is given.

Comment: My god this is it. Thank you so much. Can I assume that setting  ts.tv_nsec = 0; means that the instruction should happen right at 00000000 nanoseconds, in other words at the "stroke of the second hand"?

Comment: I'm trying to make the struct in swift and doing this: `var futureStruct = timespec(tv_sec: int64_t(timeIntervalDesired), tv_nsec: 0)`, but Swift doesn't know what int64_t is. Any chance you know the Swift way to do it? It doesn't throw an error if I do: `var futureStruct = timespec(tv_sec: Int(timeIntervalDesired), tv_nsec: 0)`, but I'm not sure if I should trust 'Int' to do the right thing there.

Comment: @LeMotJuiced the `tv_sec` has the type of `__darwin_time_t` which is just `typealias __darwin_time_t = Int` defined in `_types.h`. Hope that helps.